# Highcharts - How to set Pie Chart's background color dynamically

Tags: vue.js, charts, highcharts

I'm using the following line to change some visual properties based on some conditions

```
this.$refs.pieChart.chart.series[0].update({ dataLabels: { color: 'blue' }, chart: { backgroundColor: 'yellow' } })
```

This works fine for the dataLabels part, but I'm unable to change the backgroundColor one.

I tried this:

```
this.$refs.pieChart.chart.series[0].update({ dataLabels: { color: 'blue' }, backgroundColor: 'yellow' })
```

and this

```
this.$refs.pieChart.chart.series[0].update({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' })
```

With no luck, I searched everywhere else in my code, nothing is overriding or setting the **backgroundColor**
side.

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the slices in the pie chart or just the background of the entire chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do an update on the whole chart config, not on the series:

```
chart.update({
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
})
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.backgroundColor

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p7yg386x/